# Why is row-fluid being pushed over? (Bootstrap, CSS)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page that looks great in high resolution (1st screenshot) but in low resolution (second screenshot) row-fluid is being pushed over (so it's not in line with the VG-ES list item). Is there a way to fix this?

My Markup:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span8">Calendar</div>
    <div class="span4">Event info</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how it should look (1280 x 720):
[image: High]

This is how it looks in low resolution (1152x720 or lower)
[image: Low]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue is that you want the calender to stay in the same position relative to the top menu, double check that the menu is also in a container > row-fluid grid. If it is, then try forcing the calendar to align left.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

from the little experience I had with bootstrap this is just simply the way it is. bootstrap has some resolution key points defined through css media queries at the resolutions you mentioned.
you can edit the css media queries to meet your own needs.